# Мультирегиональность с помощью яндекса

Tags: yandex-maps-api, seo, yandex-maps-jsapi, геолокация, geoip

На клиенте уже используется яндекс для определения местоположения, поиска по адресам и т.п. https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation, поэтому хотелось бы решить задачу одним инструментом.

Для seo хочется знать хотя бы региональный центр юзера на стороне сервера. Т.к. от этого будет зависеть контент, цены и прочее.
Идея: продвигать основные региональные центры, но для удобства юзера и более точных расчётов давать ему выбирать станицы, деревни и т.д.

Задача:
Определить местоположение по ip на сервере. Смаппить местоположение с поддоменом (Петергоф -> https://spb.example.com)
Перенаправлять пользователя на поддомен.
На сервере по поддомену spb надо определить название и координаты для.

Далее если пользователь на клиенте изменяет своё местоположение на деревня Ваутинки (что в Москве), то перенаправить его на поддомен https://msk.example.com

Есть ли возможность средствами яндекса решить задачу? Или сервис для получения основных региональных центров РФ, их координат и названий для поддомена?

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно у Яндекса такого API нет, но есть много других сервисов, например [модуль GeoIP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.geoip.php) для PHP.